# How can I save multiple variables output to the same file on Ansible?

Tags: ansible, cisco

I am using Ansible to manage several network devices.

So far I only used it to ease the configuration of many devices, now I would like to use it to perform some checks on the configurations of the devices.

My question is : is it possible to define a single playbook to run many commands and to get only one file with all the outputs of every command in it?

I would like to avoid 1 file per command per device..

Thank you

Comment: Why are you sending the results to a file? Ideally you'd just check the results and remediate in the script via PASS/FAIL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick:

loop.yaml:

```
- name: get something from device
  command: some_command
  register: command_output
- name: Process output
  set_fact: 
    cumulative_output: '{{ cumulative_output|default([]) + [command_output.stdout] }}'
```

main.yaml:

```
- name: Running over all devices
  include_tasks: loop.yaml
  with_items: '{{ device_list }}'
- name: Saving cumulative result
  copy:
    content: '{{ cumulative_output|join("\n") }}'
    dest: /tmp/result.txt
```

Key features:

- Use of `set_fact`, which evaluates jinja (as any other module)
- `cumulative_output` is a list of stdouts
- loop over something with `include_tasks`

I'm not sure how you gather this information and where do you store it, but I hope this example will give you overall idea: store in a list and update that list with `set_fact` trick.